# Is 'You can do...' enough polite to provide options?

Tags: phrase-usage, politeness

Suppose that I send invoices to my clients recurrently.  Sometimes the amount is too small to pay alone. In that case, I don't mind they pay with next invoice.

> You can pay it together with next one.

Is that polite?  As for me, it sounds as if I am a boss and give them some permission. That is not my intention.

I usually communicate with some clients on email and others on text chat.  So I'd like to know suitable expressions for each case. (maybe chat is less formal than email)

Comment: Although I usually argue *against* the passive voice (because it's often overdone, and it impairs legibility), in this specific case it's normal to use passive phrasing - ***It can be paid** together with next one,* for example. But this is purely a matter of conventional "business letter style". There's nothing *syntactically* wrong with your version.

Comment: It's not impolite, but it may not be 100% clear. I'd suggest: _You can wait to pay this together with your next invoice._ I would also mention: _...with no late penalty incurred._

Comment: A minor correction: *one*, in this context, is countable, so it has to be "with **the** next one."

Comment: @user75350 One way of doing it would be to include a line in all your bills stating that: *Amounts of less than X-(dollars/euros) may be held over and paid with the subsequent bill.* Or ....*....paid the following month.* depending on how often you bill your clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If politeness is your goal one alternative would be:

You *may* pay it together with the next one.

Changing *can* with *may* makes it more of an accommodation that is easily available to them. However, your original sentence will work. The word together seems to not be needed in either sentence though.